# Rendering PDFs from a database inside MVC views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

I was wondering if it's possible to do this without using 3rd party compnents in MVC 3. (I am open to free components though.) There are a couple of links out there but they seem to be mostly concerned with reporting and other code samples that do claim to do this sort of thing don't seem to compile. I'm not having any trouble saving and retrieving the PDFs to and from my database, but when I return the PDF as a `File` or a `FileStreamResult` the user is prompted with a download. A more desirable approach would be to actually render the PDFs inside the browser. I've had a look at iTextSHarp, it does the job to an extent, but it's not a complete solution. For example it will display the PDF inside the view if and only if the client has Adobe Reader installed, otherwise it prompts for a download. So technically, I'm mostly looking for a PDF viewer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41933/ASP-NET-PDF-Viewer-User-Control-Without-Acrobat-Re) seems the best solution, though I haven't tried it. It needs to be ported to C# and made MVC compatible though, but this seems to be the way to go if you don't want to splash out on a 3rd party component [like Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/pdf-viewer).

**EDIT 4th December**

I spent a good few days searching for a workaround, and I think I've found a pretty good one. There are already numerous C# wrappers for the ghostscript converter, so why not roll out your own scheme? (which I ended up doing). The wrappers:

[Mark Redman's Wrapper](http://redmanscave.blogspot.com)

[Matt Ephraim's Wrapper](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/06/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ghostscript/)

And if you want a more practical solution, there are 2 fantastic articles on Codeproject:

[How To Convert PDF to Image Using Ghostscript API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API)

[Convert a PDF into a series of images using C# and GhostScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317700/Convert-a-PDF-into-a-series-of-images-using-Csharp)

However I feel that the solution is still not optimal. For example the Ghostscript converter works with file directories, meaning that you have to generated a physical copy of the PDF file on disk for the converter to work with, would have been much better if this could have been achieved using byte arrays. There probably is a way to address that though.

**EDIT 21st December**

And finally, for the sake of completeness and answering the actual question:

After a bit more research I've concluded that the best PDF viewer at the moment is the fantastic [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) library. I've tried a few, and for me this is the best so far. I've even tried third party components ([Syncfusion's Pdf Viewer](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/aspnet-mvc/pdf-viewer)) and even that wasn't as consistent or reliable as PDF.js. The downsides of PDF.js:

1. A bit confusing and difficult to get started with, the documentation is somehwat weak
2. It only works in the latest browsers (natural since it utilises so much HTML5). I've tested it succesfully in Firefox 17 and Chrome 23. It has some problems in IE9, but works perfectly well in IE10. But I don't mind that at all. If your websites viewers expect such a powerful functionality from your application (or any other web App) then they should be using the latest technologies.
3. There doesn't seem to be a way (At least not that I'm aware of) of loading a PDF as a byte array/stream, therefore you have to create a copy of the PDF on disk if you wish to display it. Other than these negligible hiccups, PDF.js is truly amazing.

I've created a small but fully functional MVC demo of PDF.js [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE97D7BBF7088816!167&authkey=!ANYAE-mbLaosXFs).

Answer (score 2):

I´ve been using iTextSharp with good results.  I can manage to open pdf in separate window and even without Adobe installed (I´m using Foxit Reader in my comp).  Actually in my example I´m not using iTextSharp at all.

**My View:**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RetreiveFile", "File", new { id = fileId })" target="_blank">
    OpenPdf
</a>
```

**My Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult RetreiveFile(int id)
    {
        ComplexClass myClass= _FileModel.GetFile(id);
        byte[] img = myClass.ContentData.ToArray();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=xyz.pdf");
        return File(img, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Whereas my contentdata is stored in a database as binary data.

Anyway, maybe I´m misunderstanding your question but this is how I handle pdfs in my projects and my browser never asks me to download the pdf  :)

Regards.

Comment: thanks, I've been missing something since I've just been testing my code with IE 9...the solution you posted works in Chrome and FF, but not in IE. I think Chrome and FF have some built in PDF viewer whereas IE does not, therefore instantly prompts the user for a download.

Comment: mhm.... that´s actually not suprising when something has to do with IE9.  But actually my code works in IE9.  Perhaps you have some strict security settings in IE9?  (or maybe they´re just default)

Comment: Actually I think you need to have some sort of viewer installed for your browser to render the PDF properly, I unistalled Foxit reader and none of the browsers rendered the PDF anymorem instead prompted for a download...the problems still remains, a need for a PDF viewer.

Comment: hmmm.... well yes, may the viewer is a better solution for you.  Actually I´ve never dealt with those, sorry  :/

Answer (score -1):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) is the go to solution for this.